# How can I access environment variables manually added to credentials.yml.enc in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 7 and able to get the secret_key_base with the command `Rails.application.secret_key_base` but when I try get another variable that I saved in the credentials.yml.enc like `Rails.application.new_key` I get error.

Please how can I get variable that I manuelly added to the credentials.yml.enc file using the command `EDITOR='code --wait' rails credentials:edit`

Here is what my credentials.yml.enc file look like:

```
# aws:
#   access_key_id: 123
#   secret_access_key: 345

# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies.
secret_key_base: dkud
new_key: qwerty
```

I also try the command `Rails.application.credentials` it works with the `secret_key_base` but not with other variables in the credentials.yml.enc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secrets kept in the credentials file are accessible via `Rails.application.credentials`, you are missing `.credentials` to your command:

```
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.credentials.new_key
=> "qwerty"
irb(main):002:0> Rails.application.credentials[:new_key]
=> "qwerty"
```

By default only `secret_key_base` can be retrieved using `Rails.application`

Learn more on secrets in the [guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security).